# Need Help Creating BackUp directory

Tags: php, microtime

```
 $backuparray = implode("|",$songarray1);
 file_put_contents("backups/".microtime("tunes.txt"),$backuparray);
```

How do I get my backup directory to link  a txt file using microtime , owner id , premissions , and  size?  The file needs to have tunes.txt at the end of the microtime

Comment: not clear what you asking

Comment: I have to a show a backup directory on a page, I have the files showing up using the code provided, but I just need the files to show as a text file, and show the corresponding Owner ID, Permissions and size of the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = "/var/html/uploads";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
echo("<table border='1' width='100%'>\n");
echo("<tr><th>Filename</th><th>File Size</th>
<th>File Type</th></tr>\n");
$dirEntries = scandir($dir);
foreach ($dirEntries as $entry) {
    $entryFullName = ($dir . "/" . $entry);
     echo("<tr><td>" . htmlentities($entry) . "</td><td>".
     filesize($entryFullName) . "</td><td>" .
     filetype($entryFullName) . "</td></tr>\n");
}
 echo("</table>\n");
}
else
echo("<p>The directory " . htmlentities($dir) . " does not
exist.</p>");
```